# Crop video file using VLC

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I found the following command for cropping a video file using VLC:

```
vlc input.mp4 --crop=480x500+290+720
```

But after running the command, the VLC player opens and I can't see any change on the `input.mp4` file.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial using the GUI at [How to Crop and Save a Video using VLC 2.0 Media Player](http://raaviblog.com/how-to-crop-and-save-a-video-using-vlc-2-0-media-player/)

- Switch from Simple to All under *Preferences >> Tools*

  - Dig down to *Video >> Filters >> Cropadd*
  - then *Video >> Filters >> Scaling*
- and finish with *Media >> Convert >> Save*

I think it's the last step that's missing from your command line. You need to tell vlc to save the file using `-sout`. There are lots of examples on the VLC wiki, like the [Transcode page](https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode/). Building the correct options looks scary; I'd start with [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30969307/14420) and build up from there. It's the `dst=...` part that has the out filename.

`--sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1024,acodec=mpga,ab=192,channels=2,deinterlace}:standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst=MyVid.mp4}`

(changed audio codec to `mpga` as that appears to be more reliable than `mp4a`, [ref](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=113147))